# Looking for a sample/example for Adobe Air (flex) app to generate a word document

Tags: php, apache-flex, ms-word, adobe

Like the title said, I'm looking to generate a word doc (or something word can read formatted) from an Adobe Air application.  My second alternative would be to generate an HTML doc and format it like the word document but it would be more convenient to use a word processor.

I eventually will tie this to a database (probably php).

Comment: Most apps do this sort of stuff on a server side; as opposed to in a client.  Is that an option for you?

Comment: Here is tutorial for Excel document (russian, translated with Google) http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fas3coder.blogspot.com%2F2010%2F05%2Fexcel-actionscript-30.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do this on the server with something like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or you can port POI to ActionScript and do it on the client.